# android code for get push notification log when app is in backgroud using firebase

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

when I try to send the notification with custom data in Firebase I did not get the notification in the background

My Firebase service Code is:

**In On message Receive method**

```
    @Override 
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.e("fcm", "received notification");

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                int badge = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("badge"));
                String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
                String timestamp = remoteMessage.getData().get("timestamp");
                handleDataMessage(badge,message,timestamp);

                badgeStore = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("badge"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post your Firebase API request.

Comment: are you registering service in manifest file or in java code?

Answer (score 0):

please register your firebase service in menifest file

```
<service
android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Add these lines inside the application tag to set the custom default icon and custom color:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: yes, i am using that. but till did not get response in background.

Comment: I have done this in past but dint have code right now.
If you can provide any git repository for your concern then I can help you much better

Comment: follow this tutorial 
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/

Comment: ok thank you.. i got it. i used FirebaseDataReceiver :                                                                                                                                                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase